# WCF JSON service with request content encrypted

Tags: json, wcf

a Json WCF service method looks like this:

```
getFoo(MyDataType data){ ...
```

WCF automaticly translates the HTTP request that looks like:

```
  randomGuy{
       name:'John',
       age:18
    }
```

into the C# defined type

```
MyDataType{
    string name {get;set;}
    int age {get;set;}
}
```

But if I encrypt the request content, instead of receiving a request that looks like

> randomGuy{
>          name:'John',
>          age:18
>       }
>   I will receive 
>   wceweuicn23cb38v934vb398v03c264vb834gv3v7b3vb3647v34vb3v83vh38v43vhv3hv

Is there any way to first decrypt the request content into randomGuy{
       name:'John',
       age:18
    } before WCF translates the JSON object into the .net defined type MyDataType?

Answer (score 1):

To me, you have about 2 options:

- Option 1: Use SSL for the connection so the message is protected.
- Option 2: Intercept the message

In summary, I believe that the answer you are looking for are along the lines of an IClientMessageInspector which will allow you to manipulate messages and intercept them if neccessary on you WCF client.  This article should explain it somewhat - [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730107.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) or [IDispatchMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageformatter.aspx) may help you in this case. And in general check the [System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.aspx) namespace - there are other helpful staff.

The idea with IDispatchMessageInspector, that you are able to change (decrypt in your case) the incoming message before it's converted to a .NET object from JSON one.